# Is there a portable version of the Upwork Team App (time tracker) software?

Tags: portable-apps

Is there a portable version of the Upwork Team App (time tracker) software, or how do I install the original (non-portable version) on Windows 7 without admin rights?

Answer (score 1):

For those who might need the answer. I couldn't find a ready portable version of this app, however guys on another website suggested me to create my own portable pack using Cameyo (http://www.cameyo.com/). Created it online and it took me no more than 5 minutes of time. The portable version works perfectly.